# Android Studio "applications have the same package name"

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio, google-glass

My application in Android Studio has separate components for mobile devices and for Google Glasses.  When I attempt to load the mobile version onto a Nexus 10 (Android version 4.4.2) I get the following error:

```
Applications have the same package name com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer:
mobile, glass
```

I can, however, load the app onto a glass device (XE19.1) with no problem.

I find this error perplexing because my app has been running with no problem for several weeks, and all of a sudden the mobile component is crippled.  I did recently add a dependency on the glass R to the mobile component, but even this was a few days before this error showed itself.

I tried refactoring the mobile directory, as well as the whole package, with no success.

I have searched SO and other sources but I didn't find any duplicates; please link me if I am wrong on this point.  Thanks for the help.  Provided manifests are below.

**Mobile manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.FileRetrieval"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.BluetoothClient"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bluetooth_client" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

**Glass Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.LauncherActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_launcher" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.LiveCardMenuActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MenuTheme" >
    </activity>

    <!-- Service responsible for maintaining LiveCard -->
    <service
        android:name="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.LiveCardDataCollect"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_glass_logo"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_live_card_data_collect" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
            android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger" />
    </service>

    <!-- For content sharing permissions -->
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

    <!-- Selects file for sharing to client. -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.FileShareActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_file_share" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.BluetoothHost"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bluetooth_host" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.carterpedersen.datatransfer.BluetoothHost$HostBroadRec" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="transapps.g6.new.alert" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using just one manifest (combined for use on both mobile and Glass - I'm assuming one apk correct?)

Answer (score 0):

Just close completely the android studio and reopen it. My problem solved after this.

By the way you can try this command on cmd:

```
adb uninstall com.your.package
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the `package` name in each of the AndroidManifest.xml files. So, for example, change to:

**Mobile**

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.carterpedersen.mobile.datatransfer" >
```

**Glass**

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.carterpedersen.glass.datatransfer" >
```

The package name should be unique amongst applications. Refer to the [`package` attribute definition](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html).